# Find IDs by comparing or currect subsetting of two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, rows

I have two data frames as the following:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L), x = c(5L, 
2L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 6L), y = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
8L), ID = 44:51), .Names = c("Freq", "x", "y", "ID"), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Freq: int  1 1 1 1 0 0 2 1
 $ x   : int  5 2 8 6 3 4 8 6
 $ y   : int  1 4 2 3 5 6 8 8
 $ ID  : int  44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51
```

and the second one:

```
 > dput(df2)
 structure(list(Freq = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), x = c(5L, 2L, 8L, 6L
 ), y = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("Freq", "x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
 > str(df2)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Freq: int  1 1 1 1
 $ x   : int  5 2 8 6
 $ y   : int  1 4 2 3
```

I would like to find the IDs for df2 from df1, so my desired output would be :

```
 44 45 46 47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using **[`base::merge()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/merge)**

```
# Using OPs data
merge(df1, df2)$ID
# [1] 45 44 47 46
```

Here `merge` takes two data frames and merges them by shared column names (ie., subsets `df1` by `df2`).

Comment: Thanks!This is what I wanted.